# How to edit existing word file using POI API

Tags: java, apache-poi

Using:

XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

How do I assign it so it doesn't overwrite the file if it already exists?

Answer (score 5):

The following will create a brand new, empty XWPF Word Document to work with:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
```

Whereas this will open up an existing one for editing:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("MyFile.docx"));
```

Or if you have an `InputStream` rather than a file:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(inputStream);
```